# Scala Constructor Confusion - please clarify

Tags: java, scala, constructor

I am very confused by Scala Constructors. For example, I have the following classes that represent a tree with operators such as Add and leaf nodes on the tree that are numbers.

```
abstract class Node(symbol: String) {}

abstract class Operator(symbol: String,
      binaryOp: (Double, Double) => Double ) extends Node(symbol) {
}

class Add(a: Number, b: Number) extends 
      Operator("+", (a: Double, b: Double) => a+b ) {
}

class Number(symbol: String) extends Node(symbol) {
    val value = symbol.toDouble
    def this(num: Double) {
      this(num.toString)
    }
}
```

I read in one site that what goes in a Scala constructor is automatically immutable (val), but this guy on Stack Overflow said ["The input parameters for the constructor are not vals unless you say they are."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223959/must-override-val-variable-in-scala) So that's one contradiction.

Also, I apparently may or may not need to add "val" and "override" into the constructors for some reason? I mean I want everything to be public and immutable and for Add to have a symbol equal to "+", a binaryOp equal to the addition function, and also two numbers a and b. Can someone please explain how to get the constructors to work as expected in Scala in a non-verbose way?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
addition = Add(Number(1), Number(2))
addition.binaryOp(addition.a.value, addition.b.value)
```

Comment: The REPL calls class parameters vals. `class C(x: Int){ def mod(y:Int):Unit = x=y }` produces `error: reassignment to val`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there: Every argument to the constructor of a Scala class is thrown away after construction of the class, unless a method of the class uses it. In this case, it is made a `private[this] val`.

However, you can simply add the `val`/`var` keyword in front of your constructor parameter and it will be made a public `val`/`var`:

```
abstract class Node(val symbol: String) {}
```

Usually, this is not repeated in the constructor for subclasses if the field is already defined in the superclass:

```
abstract class Operator(symbol: String, // no val here, only pass to super class
      val binaryOp: (Double, Double) => Double) extends Node(symbol) {
}

class Add(val a: Number, val b: Number) extends 
  Operator("+", (a: Double, b: Double) => a+b ) {
}
```

Now you can access the fields from outside the class:

```
addition = Add(Number(1), Number(2))
addition.binaryOp(addition.a.value, addition.b.value)
```

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that case classes are somewhat different (parameters are public `vals`s by default), since that could be another source of confusion.