# How to convert Java constructor to Scala one with a stack as one member attribute?

Tags: scala

```
public class BSTIterator {
private Stack<TreeNode> stk;
public BSTIterator(TreeNode root) {
    stk = new Stack<>();
    while (root != null) {
        stk.push(root);
        root = root.left;
    }

}

/**
 * @return whether we have a next smallest number
 */
public boolean hasNext() {
    return !stk.isEmpty();

}

/**
 * @return the next smallest number
 */
public int next() {
    TreeNode curr = stk.pop();
    int res = curr.val;
    curr = curr.right;
    while (curr != null) {
        stk.push(curr);
        curr = curr.left;
    }
    return res;

}
```

}

above is the java code snippet. how do i convert it to a scala class? I'm confused by the constructor part. how do i set up a constructor in this case?

```
 var obj = new BSTIterator(root)
 var param_1 = obj.next()
 var param_2 = obj.hasNext()
```

Comment: http://joelabrahamsson.com/learning-scala-part-four-classes-and-constructors/

Comment: Create a class make companion object in that you can do what you want else you can use def this which is auxiliary constructor and there you go.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Constructor Confusion - please clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33228711/scala-constructor-confusion-please-clarify)

Comment: @RamanMishra There's just a single constructor here, no auxiliary constructors or companion objects needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor parameters go on the class and can simply be used inside. You can also put statements directly in the body of the class and they become part of the constructor:

```
class BSTIterator(root: TreeNode) {
  private val stk: Stack[TreeNode] = new Stack()

  {
    var root_ = root // you can't change parameters in Scala
    while (root_ != null) {
      stk.push(root_)
      root_ = root_.left
    }
  }

    ...
}
```

The block is used so `root_` doesn't become a field of the class. Also, you'd normally use Scala collections instead of Java `Stack`, but I'll leave that part to you.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally kept wrong generics from Java, that may be the problem. But in general, you need to say what didn't work.