# Why I need override modifier when creating a class argument with val?

Tags: scala

Why do I need `override` modifier if a class argument is declared as `val` but not otherwise?

```
scala> class A(val s:String){}
defined class A

scala> class B(val s:String) extends A(s) //doesnot work without override
<console>:13: error: overriding value s in class A of type String;
 value s needs `override' modifier
       class B(val s:String) extends A(s)
                   ^

scala> class A(s:String){}
defined class A

scala> class B(s:String) extends A(s) //override not required.
defined class B
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only is `override` not required in the second example; it isn't allowed, because `s` doesn't override anything. If a constructor parameter isn't a `val`, that it doesn't form part of the class's API, so there's nothing to override.

When you use `val`, as in the first example, in addition to the constructor parameter `s`, you also implicitly introduce a method named `s`. So when you extend `A`, Scala requires the `override` keyword to force you to acknowledge that you are introducing a new, *different* `s` that shadows the one in `A`; this is an unusual thing to do, and they don't want you to be able to do it by accident.

Comment: so if I do not provide a modifier like `val` or `var`, Scala compiler will not create a class member. Thus no override is required.

Comment: Actually, it may create a _private_ member if it's used outside the constructor, but those can't be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223959/must-override-val-variable-in-scala). Apparently the compiler needs it.  When looking at the assembly of the 'overriden' example with **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javap" -p -c -constants -s -verbose B.class**, there is indeed an extra string created that references the string in class A

```
  {
    public java.lang.String s();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #12                 // Method A.s:()Ljava/lang/String;
         4: areturn
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   LB;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 8: 0

  public B(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=2, args_size=2
         0: aload_0
         1: aload_1
         2: invokespecial #18                 // Method A."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
         5: return
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       6     0  this   LB;
            0       6     1     s   Ljava/lang/String;
      LineNumberTable:
        line 8: 0
}
```